# Android ActionBar don't display tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am developing for Android 4 (SDK version 15) and use the native actionbar without any support library.

So far it has been easy and straightforward for me to work with the actionbar, but now when I try to add tabs it is impossible for me to make them show.

In order to find the problem I made a new activity and removed everything but the simplest possible tab functionality but still I cannot see any tabs.

Is there anyone who has any idea why tabs don't show up for me?

Here is my current super simple tab activity:

```
public class MyTabActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set the tabs.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Tab 1")
            .setTabListener(new MyTabListener()));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Tab 2")
            .setTabListener(new MyTabListener()));
}

private static class MyTabListener implements TabListener {

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
}
```

The result of starting the activity is an actionbar with only the application icon in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, this was a stupid mistake.

Instead of:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

it should be:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Set the tabs.
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
        .setText("Tab 1")
        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener()));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
        .setText("Tab 2")
        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener()));
```

add navigation mode after the tabs adding to it..

```
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't help.

Comment: I use a slight customization of Theme.Holo. I just tried removing the theme but id didn't help. In what way could the theme prohibit the tabs from showing?

Answer (score 0):

Add `actionBar.show();` in your code.

Instead of actionbar tabs you can use Pagerslidetabstrip library.
It is simple and very user friendly.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't help. The actionbar is showing but there are no tabs.

Comment: try to use Pagerslidetabstrip library you can download it from github.

Comment: Thank you but I only need the regular actionbar to show tabs for me.